# Fill and append data dynamically from mutiple OledbConnections to one single OleDbDataAdapter

Tags: c#, .net, excel

I'm trying to dynamically add rows from some excel files located in a directory to a OleDbDataAdapter.
So far,I managed to add some data to the OleDbDataAdapter by dynamically generating OleDbConnections that each point to the respective excel files from which i want to read data. However, the code stops after reading the first excel file. I suspect that I have to clear some variables but I'm kinda stuck for now.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApp35
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string dirALC_EDC = @"C:\Users\________\Desktop\Mission\Fichiers\ALC_EDC\";
            var files = Directory.GetFiles(dirALC_EDC, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);


            foreach (string file in files)
            {
                String theConnString = (String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0\"", file));

                OleDbConnection excelConnection = new OleDbConnection(theConnString);
                excelConnection.Open();
                var dt = new DataTable();
                var da = new OleDbDataAdapter();
                var _command = new OleDbCommand();
                _command.Connection = excelConnection;
                _command.CommandText = "select * FROM [Sheet1$]";
                da.SelectCommand = _command;

                try
                {
                    da.Fill(dt);

                    for (int i = 4; i <= dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", dt.Rows[i].ItemArray));
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    // process error here
                }

                Console.ReadLine();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have `Console.ReadLine();` inside the loop and you're filling a single DataTable anyway. You should add the DataTables you create to a DataSet.

Comment: Hi Jimi, after removing Console.ReadLine(); it became apparent that the DataTable was getting filled by all the Excel files. What is a DataSet in c# and what's the benefit from creating one if all my data is in fact in the datatable?

Comment: A [DataSet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataset) can store multiple DataTables (and create relationships between them, if required, plus other functions). Here, you're querying multiple Excel worksheets, so you need to store the data in multiple DataTables. A DataSet can be used as a collector of DataTable objects.